# Regular expression to return string from filename

Tags: regex

How to write a generic regular expression that will
1) capture string after first _ and  before second _ as group 1
2) capture string after last _ as group 2

Example

```
ASIA_JAP_TOKYO_201109
```

OUTPUT Would be

```
group 1 - JAP   
group 2 - 201109
```

Comment: `/^[^_]+_([^_]+).*_([^_]+)$/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex like

```
/^[^_]+_([^_]+).*_([^_]+)$/
```

---

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/kB6jY0/2)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
^[^_]*_([^_]*).*_([^_]*)$
```

Here first captured group will be "JAP" and second will be "201109".

- `^[^_]*_` matches upto the first `_` from start
- The first captured group, `([^_]*)` captures the string upto next `_`
- `.*_` greedily matches upto the last `_`
- `([^_]*)$` matches the string after last `_` and put it in captured group 2.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vL2lP7/4)

Answer (score 1):

For readability purposes, I might use two separate regular expression for this:

First regex:

```
^[^_]*_([^_]*?)_(.*)$
```

Second regex:

```
^(.*)_([^_]*)$
```

But if you are using a tool such as Java or Perl, I would much rather split the string on underscore and extract out the pieces you want.